# jquery .offset().top doesn't have the expected behavior

Tags: jquery, html, css

I 'm using the **jquery .offset().top** to build a fixed menu on my website and it works absolutely perfect but ONLY when the user look at the top of the page. If you try to scroll the body down to the middle and then try to click at the left links of the menu the scroll has strange behavior and doesn't display the correct anchors anymore or even worst stops to work completely. Why is that? What i 'm doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var $wrapper = $('.popup-cats-wrapper');

  $('.black-btn').click(function() {
    $wrapper.animate({
      scrollTop: $wrapper.scrollTop() + $(".black-anchor").offset().top - 10
    }, 400)
  });
  $('.red-btn').click(function() {
    $wrapper.animate({
      scrollTop: $wrapper.scrollTop() + $(".red-anchor").offset().top - 10
    }, 400)
  });
  $('.green-btn').click(function() {
    $wrapper.animate({
      scrollTop: $wrapper.scrollTop() + $(".green-anchor").offset().top - 10
    }, 400)
  });
  $('.blue-btn').click(function() {
    $wrapper.animate({
      scrollTop: $wrapper.scrollTop() + $(".blue-anchor").offset().top - 10
    }, 400)
  });


});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "sans";
  height:2000px
}

.hero-categories-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  position:fixed;
}

.popup-cats-wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #aaa;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.categories-sidebar {
  width: 120px;
  background: #ececef;
  height: 200px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.popup-menu-row {
  padding: 5px 8px;
  color: #212121;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.color-block {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.cat-title {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>


<div class="hero-categories-wrap">

  <div class="categories-sidebar">
    <div class="popup-menu-row black-btn">BLACK</div>
    <div class="popup-menu-row red-btn">RED</div>
    <div class="popup-menu-row green-btn">GREEN</div>
    <div class="popup-menu-row blue-btn">BLUE</div>
  </div>
  <div class="popup-cats-wrapper">

    <div class="color-block">
      <div class="cat-title black-anchor">BLACK COLOR</div>
      <div class="cat-description">Black is the darkest color, the result of the absence or complete absorption of visible light. It is an achromatic color, a color without hue, like white and gray.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="color-block">
      <div class="cat-title red-anchor">RED COLOR</div>
      <div class="cat-description">Red is the color at the end of the visible spectrum of light, next to orange and opposite violet. It has a dominant wavelength of approximately 625–740 nanometres. It is a primary color in the RGB color model and the CMYK color model, and is the
        complementary color of cyan.</div>
    </div>


    <div class="color-block">
      <div class="cat-title green-anchor">GREEN COLOR</div>
      <div class="cat-description">Green is the color between blue and yellow on the visible spectrum. It is evoked by light which has a dominant wavelength of roughly 495–570 nm. </div>
    </div>

    <div class="color-block">
      <div class="cat-title blue-anchor">BLUE COLOR</div>
      <div class="cat-description">Blue is one of the three primary colours of pigments in painting and traditional colour theory, as well as in the RGB colour model. It lies between violet and green on the spectrum of visible light. The eye perceives blue when observing light with
        a dominant wavelength between approximately 450 and 495 nanometres. Most blues contain a slight mixture of other colours; azure contains some green, while ultramarine contains some violet.</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: as I can see it is working fine. can you please make come video what's the issue?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment @OMiShah. If you try to scroll down the body of my snippet to the middle and then click on the left links of the menu you will see what i mean. Anchors doesnt work anymore. it display the wrong anchors at the right side. Just scroll down the body NOT the fixed element.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358026/scroll-issue-of-scrollable-dynamic-content-in-fixed-container

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want a position more relative. Change `.offset()` into `.position()` so it won't compare to the root position every time you move your window.